# Expo files isn't readable

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm tryna get read tha content of this recorded file with expo FileSystem api.

this is the code:

```
Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync((Platform.OS==='android'?'file://':'')+sound.status.uri).then(str => {
  console.log(str)
})
```

I got this error and when I tried to move it access it with any FileSystem method it throws tha same error.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with reading a pdf from a document picker.

Spend a lot of time trying to search for a solution. nothing worked. I even build the app and nothing changed.

So instead of using FileSystem, I used file reader:

```html
const convertToBase64 = async (uri) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setBase64Data(reader.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error converting to base64:", error);
      Alert.alert("Error converting to base64");
    }
  };
```

this worked perfectly for reading the PDF and it should also work for all other file types; however, keep in mind that if your file is too large (> 3MB) the base64 might be too large causing your app to crash.

You might also need to downgrade whatwg-fetch to 3.6.